# How do I get a decimal value when using the division operator in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, syntax, operators

For example, the standard division symbol '/' rounds to zero:

```
>>> 4 / 100
0
```

However, I want it to return 0.04. What do I use?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

There are three options:

```
>>> 4 / float(100)
0.04
>>> 4 / 100.0
0.04
```

which is the same behavior as the C, C++, Java etc, or

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 4 / 100
0.04
```

You can also activate this behavior by passing the argument `-Qnew` to the Python interpreter:

```
$ python -Qnew
>>> 4 / 100
0.04
```

The second option will be the default in Python 3.0. If you want to have the old integer division, you have to use the `//` operator.

**Edit**: added section about `-Qnew`, thanks to [ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6899/)!

Comment: Please also add the availability of `python -Q new` command-line option to make your answer more complete.

Comment: This gives a floating point value, not a decimal value.  See Glyph's answer.

Comment: You can also use `from __future__ import division` in the source code.

Comment: And yet people say python is a great programming language for math... I don't know what's the worse here, using a special import which may change the behaviour if removed, or specifying float operation everywhere.

Answer (score 27):

Other answers suggest how to get a floating-point value.  While this wlil be close to what you want, it won't be exact:

```
>>> 0.4/100.
0.0040000000000000001
```

If you actually want a *decimal* value, do this:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal('4') / decimal.Decimal('100')
Decimal("0.04")
```

That will give you an object that properly knows that 4 / 100 in *base 10* is "0.04".  Floating-point numbers are actually in base 2, i.e. binary, not decimal.

Comment: why does 0.4÷100 give 0.0040000000000000001 instead of just 0.004?

Comment: Because the actual representation of the number is in binary, and since it has to use a *finite* amount of binary decimal places, the repeating pattern that would produce 4/1000 exactly cannot be represented, in the same way that you cannot represent 1/3 in decimal; 0.33333333333333333 is still less than 1/3; you have to keep going out to infinity.  I have written some more aobut this here: https://blog.glyph.im/2019/10/the-numbers-they-lie.html

Comment: Nowadays, even `repr` will round this off for you, so you can see the *full* decimal representation by expanding the precision with an `f` string: `f"{0.004:.100}"` results in `'0.0040000000000000000832667268468867405317723751068115234375'` .

Answer (score 8):

Make one or both of the terms a floating point number, like so:

```
4.0/100.0
```

Alternatively, turn on the feature that will be default in Python 3.0, 'true division', that does what you want. At the top of your module or script, do:

```
from __future__ import division
```

Answer (score 6):

You might want to look at Python's [decimal](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-decimal.html) package, also.  This will provide nice decimal results.

```
>>> decimal.Decimal('4')/100
Decimal("0.04")
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to tell Python to use floating point values, not integers. You can do that simply by using a decimal point yourself in the inputs:

```
>>> 4/100.0
0.040000000000000001
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple route 4 / 100.0

or

4.0 / 100

Answer (score 2):

You cant get a decimal value by dividing one integer with another, you'll allways get an integer that way (result truncated to integer). You need at least one value to be a decimal number.

Comment: Please note that this won't be the case anymore in Python 3.0 if you use /.

Answer (score 2):

Here we have two possible cases given below

```
from __future__ import division

print(4/100)
print(4//100)
```

Comment: for python3 you don't require that import division line just use print statements for python2 you need to explicitly add import statement

Answer (score 0):

Try 4.0/100

Answer (score 0):

Add the following function in your code with its callback.

```
# Starting of the function
def divide(number_one, number_two, decimal_place = 4):
    quotient = number_one/number_two
    remainder = number_one % number_two
    if remainder != 0:
        quotient_str = str(quotient)
        for loop in range(0, decimal_place):
            if loop == 0:
                quotient_str += "."
            surplus_quotient = (remainder * 10) / number_two
            quotient_str += str(surplus_quotient)
            remainder = (remainder * 10) % number_two
            if remainder == 0:
                break
        return float(quotient_str)
    else:
        return quotient
#Ending of the function

# Calling back the above function
# Structure : divide(<divident>, <divisor>, <decimal place(optional)>)
divide(1, 7, 10) # Output : 0.1428571428
# OR
divide(1, 7) # Output : 0.1428
```

This function works on the basis of "Euclid Division Algorithm". This function is very useful if you don't want to import any external header files in your project.

Syntex : divide([divident], [divisor], [decimal place(optional))

Code : `divide(1, 7, 10)` OR `divide(1, 7)`

Comment below for any queries.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try adding a ".0" at the end of the number.

4.0/100.0

Answer (score -1):

It's only dropping the fractional part after decimal.
Have you tried :  4.0 / 100

Answer (score -3):

Import division from future library like this:

```
from__future__ import division
```

Comment: Please add details why this would solve the original issue, and perhaps what disadvantages this approach has.