# how to make python to return floating point?

Tags: python

I want python to return 0.5 if I write 1/2 (and not 1.0/2.0).
how do I make python to return the floating point?
(I tried using getcontext().prec form decimal module)

thanks

Ariel

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117250/how-do-i-get-a-decimal-value-when-using-the-division-operator-in-python

Answer (score 8):

Use this, or switch to Python 3.0+

```
from __future__ import division
```

Comment: Also, you can use the `-Qnew` option when running Python 2.x

Answer (score 4):

```
from __future__ import division
```

Answer (score 3):

Python 3.x works the way you want by default.

Python 2.2 and greater support `from __future__ import division`, which makes / return floating point.  There is also the // operator that still performs integer division when needed.

Also see [PEP238 - Changing the Division Operator](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/).