# Why is this division not performed correctly?

Tags: python, python-2.x, division

I've a strange issue in Python: the division is not performed correctly:

```
print pointB[1]
print pointA[1]
print pointB[0]
print pointA[0]
print  (pointB[1]-pointA[1]) / (pointB[0]-pointA[0])
```

These are the results:

```
100
50
100
40
0
```

thanks

Comment: its integer division in py 2.x, ie `5/6 = 0`, try to cast denom or numerator to float first

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117250/how-do-i-get-a-decimal-value-when-using-the-division-operator-in-python, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787249/why-doesnt-this-division-work-in-python, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958684/python-division

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The above behavior is true for Python 2. The behavior of `/` was fixed in Python 3. In Python 2 you can use:

```
from __future__ import division
```

and then use `/` to get the result you desire.

```
>>> 5 / 2
2
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 5 / 2
2.5
```

Since you are dividing two integers, you get the result as an integer.

Or, change one of the numbers to a `float`.

```
>>> 5.0 / 2
2.5
```

Comment: I'm not sure that it needs to be 'fixed' - the integer division works as it's supposed to do. Plus Python 3 has been out for almost 2 years...

Comment: I will quote PEP238, `This makes expressions expecting float or complex results error-prone when integers are not expected but possible as inputs.` Also I doubt that he would be using Python 3.0 since I guess everyone makes it clear to stick to 2.6 for now. But I am also learning, so I maybe wrong.

Comment: Many languages use integer division the Python 2 way (which isn't surprising if they lack dynamic typing). I guess that it was considered a design flaw though, or it wouldn't have been changed :) Btw the latest versions are 2.7 and 3.1 (with 3.2 already in alpha).

Comment: small typo in first code example: `from __future__ import divis*i*on`

Comment: @ScottGriffiths it was considered a design flaw already over 15 years ago

Answer (score 9):

It is done correctly.

50/60 = 0

Maybe you are looking for 50.0/60.0 = 0.83333333333333337, you can cast your variables to float to get that:

```
print  float(pointB[1]-pointA[1]) / (pointB[0]-pointA[0])
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how integer division works in python. Either use floats or convert to float in your calculation:

```
float(pointB[1]-pointA[1]) / (pointB[0]-pointA[0])
```

Comment: Casting to float does not really work correctly in all cases.