# Python - Decimals not appearing

Tags: python-2.7

I'm doing a very basic calculation, but the decimals are not appearing. What am I missing?

```
a = 10/3

print a
3
```

Why the decimals are not showing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a decimal value when using the division operator in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117250/how-do-i-get-a-decimal-value-when-using-the-division-operator-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get decimals, you have to use

```
a= 10.0/3.0
print a


result : 3.33333333333
```

Normally python does just integer division if you just provide integers.